# strange issue passing a JSON object to c# method (with a collection as a parameter (using JQuery Widgets)

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm facing a strange issue when passing the following:

```
queueNotificationData = {
            StartDate: that.batchData.StartDate.valueOf(),
            StartTime: that.batchData.StartTime.valueOf(),
            EndDate: that.batchData.EndDate.valueOf(),
            EndTime: that.batchData.EndTime.valueOf(),
            ETR: that.batchData.ETR.valueOf(),
            PTW: that.batchData.PTW.valueOf(),
            SelectedTemplate: that.batchData.SelectedTemplate.valueOf(),
            IncidentFlag: that.batchData.IncidentFlag.valueOf(),
            IncidentNumber: that.batchData.IncidentNumber.valueOf(),
            SendToSubscriber: that.batchData.SendToSubscriber.valueOf(),
            SendToCustomer: that.batchData.SendToCustomer.valueOf(),
            SendToSMC: that.batchData.SendToSMC.valueOf(),
            BatchServiceIds: that.serviceIds,
            DescriptionOfWorks: that.batchData.DescriptionOfWorks.valueOf(),
            AffectedCustomerVOs: that.customerVOs
        }
```

The issue is with the AffectedCustomerVOs parameter - this is retrieved from an earlier call and is passed through a series of widgets (it's part of a pretty long wizard form)

This is the code that calls the c# method to actually do the processing:

```
this.options.sendRequest({
                url: this.options.dataUrl,
                data: queueNotificationData,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    that.data = data;
                    that._showSavedMessage();
                },
                error: function () {
                    that._showErrorMessage();
                }
            });
```

and here is the c# method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult QueueNotificationBatch(QueueNotificationInputModel param)
    {
         //do some work - code not included
    }
```

where QueueNotificationInputModel is

```
public class QueueNotificationInputModel
{
    public string BatchServiceIds { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerVO> AffectedCustomerVOs { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string ETR { get; set; }
    public string PTW { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
    public string IncidentFlag { get; set; }
    public string IncidentNumber { get; set; }
    public bool SendToSubscriber { get; set; }
    public bool SendToCustomer { get; set; }
    public bool SendToSMC { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionOfWorks { get; set; }

    public QueueNotificationInputModel()
    {
        AffectedCustomerVOs = new List<CustomerVO>();
    }
}
```

Now - all this code seems to work fine - the C# method is successfully called and the values passed in are good except for AffectedCustomerVOs. The list has 3 items in it (this is correct) but the items within the list have no values - all nulls/0's. If I put alert(that.customerVOs[0]['Email']); immediately before creating the queueNotificationData object, it correctly displays "test@test.com" but this value never makes it into the c# method.

I assume it's some sort of serialization problem but I can't figure out where? Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending this complex object as JSON serialized:

```
this.options.sendRequest({
    url: this.options.dataUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(queueNotificationData),
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        that.data = data;
        that._showSavedMessage();
    },
    error: function () {
        that._showErrorMessage();
    }
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method shown here is natively built in modern browsers. If you need to support legacy browsers you might need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Comment: Great - works fine now. I had a feeling it was a serialization issue - is there any rule as to when stringify must be used and when it is safe to simply pass the straight JSON through? I would have expected it to either fail in all cases rather than it work on several widgets but fail on this "complex" one